# Convert x,y coordinates after resize in PHP

Tags: php, math, gd

This is quite a complicated and brain busting question, so please read carefully and don't just skim through. Thanks!

I'm extracting images from a PDF file and rebuilding the page image. It's all working except I can't get the coordinates just right for placing the little images over the larger background image.

I start with something like this:

```
$page_width = 1000;
$page_height = 1500;
$back_img_x = 5
$back_img_y = 8
$back_img_width = 990;
$back_img_height = 1501;
$back_img_truewidth = 3000;
$back_img_trueheight = 4000;
$little_img_x = 550;
$little_img_y = 250;
$little_img_width = 200;
$little_img_height = 100;
```

Now to explain, the back image is not necessarily the same size as the page, which means it's being scaled, it is also not necessarily position at 0,0 which is due to whoever the stupid person was who made the PDF in the first place (or which application.)

What I now do is ignore the page size and try to map the little image onto the back image in the correct position after trimming the back image.

So lots of complicated things are now done to the back image, which results in the following:

```
$trimleft = 100;
$trimright = 100;
$trimtop = 40;
$trimbottom = 120;
$margin_x = 50;
$margin_y = 35
$offset_x = 0;
$offset_y = 90;
```

The back image is then correctly trimmed and placed upon a new canvas like this:

```
$fullwidth=($trimright-$trimleft)+($margin_x*2);
$fullheight=($trimbottom-$trimtop)+($margin_y*2);
$trimmed=imagecreate($fullwidth,$fullheight);
imagefill($trimmed,0,0,imagecolorallocate($trimmed,255,255,255)); // make white
imagecopy($trimmed,$image,$margin_x+$offset_x,$margin_y+$offset_y,$trimleft,$trimtop,$trimright-$trimleft,$trimbottom-$trimtop);
```

So far so good...

Now I want to find the x, y, width & height of the little image to be in the correct position over the background image.

I do this:

```
$little_img_width=($little_img_width/$back_img_width);
$little_img_height=($little_img_height/$back_img_height);
$little_img_x=(($little_img_x-$back_img_x)/$back_img_width)*$back_img_truewidth;
$little_img_y=(($little_img_y-$back_img_y)/$back_img_height)*$back_img_trueheight;

$little_img_width*=($back_img_truewidth/$fullwidth);
$little_img_height*=($back_img_trueheight/$fullheight);
$little_img_x=($little_img_x-$trimleft+$margin_x+$offset_x)/$fullwidth;
$little_img_y=($little_img_y-$trimtop+$margin_y+$offset_y)/$fullheight;
```

That should give me the correct x, y, width & height of the little image, correctly positioned and sized on the background image (in percentage where 0 is far left and 1 is far right, etc.) The width/height are correct but the coordinates are very slightly off. It is the y coordinate that is too low on the page by about 5%. Note that `$offset_x` is 0, which would suggest that the problem lies with the offset variables (since `$offset_x` is 0, it is not showing an positioning error for x axis, only y axis).

I've been staring at these values for days and rewritten them all a few times. This time it all looks perfect to me. I don't understand what is still wrong.

Comment: should `$little_img_x` and `$little_img_y` be multiplied byt the ratio in the last code sample? Right now it is set to be equal to the ratio, which could be part of the problem.

Comment: What part are you referring to? Right now the width & height are kept as 0-1 percentage the whole way through, but the x & y are converted to the true width/height of the background image so that the offsets and margins can be applied before they are then converted in the 0-1 percentage. The `($back_img_truewidth/$fullwidth)` ratio doesn't apply to x,y because that was only to keep the width and height correct with the change in margins on the image, whereas for x & y the new margin value is simply added on.

Comment: Nevermind, I see how it works now. But I also noticed that you are dividing by `$fullwidth` and height, which means that your resulting value is going to be off by about `<your_additions>/$fullwidth` or the value of `$little_img_x` and the same for height.

Comment: I don't understand, could you please explain more (perhaps make it an answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding the math correctly, here's what's happening:

You have `$fullwidth` and `$fullheight` which are the width and height that the image will be occupying on your canvas.

You then multiply the smaller image's width and height by the ratio of its size to the full size in the original, unprocessed image. Which is correct.

However, when you are calculating `$little_img_x` and `$little_img_y`, you are doing this:

```
$little_img_x=(($little_img_x-$back_img_x)/$back_img_width)*$back_img_truewidth;
$little_img_y=(($little_img_y-$back_img_y)/$back_img_height)*$back_img_trueheight;
```

This ends up returning an awkwardly arbitrary number (something like 150 for x and 100 for y), which I can't find any possible use for.

You then go on and use that value to calculate the new x and y for the little image, which would result in another arbitrary number which shows no purpose.

I propose a new approach where `$little_img_x` and `$little_img_y` are calculated as follows:

```
$little_img_x = ($little_img_x/$back_img_x)*$fullwidth + (($little_img_x-$trimleft+$margin_x+$offset_x) / $fullwidth)
$little_img_y = ($little_img_y/$back_img_y)*fullheight + (($little_img_y-$trimtop+$margin_y+$offset_y)/ $fullheight)
```

Basically, we take the little image's original x, get its ratio to the background's x, multiply it by the new width to get the presented x, and then add all of the offset processing. We do the same thing with y.

I have no idea if this works, but I hope it does. Good luck!

Comment: I was offline for a bit... I'll give this a try now. Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm... actually there was nothing wrong with my code, the issue was that PDFs apparently measure y from the bottom instead of the top. But I figured this out after testing your code and seeing how it changed, so you did help to fix the problem and I appreciate your help.

Comment: Weird. Good thing to know if I ever deal with PDFs.